# System app was not signed correctly

Tags: updates, system-apps, signature-error

My phone shipped with an outdated version of TouchPal. When I try to update the app through the Play Store, I get this error:

> Package file was not signed correctly. Uninstall the previous copy of
>   the app and try again.

The thing is: the app is a system app, therefore I can't uninstall it.

How can I get the app up to date?

My old phone had it preinstalled as well, and the update there went on without problems. What?

Comment: If you want, root your phone and uninstall it that way (deleting the `.apk` in `/system/app/` is enough). Then you can install it. Note: you lose all settings/application data of that app.

Comment: @GiantTree That's what first came to my mind as well, but I'd prefer not to root.

Comment: Then you are not able to install the updated TouchPal. Unless you find a way to install an application with an invalid certificate.

Comment: @GiantTree That's what I asked for here.

Comment: Well, it's not possible without rooting. That's your problem.